# MongoDB $limit inside an $and

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, aggregate

I'm looking to implement a query that will return me a single JSON with 2 sets of data together.

What I look for is to retrieve 40 orders which offerDate is still in the future ( $gte: today ) and 8 orders which offerDate is in the past.

Currently I only have the 40 in the future like so:

```
const orders = await db.Order.aggregate([
    {
      $match: {
        offerDate: {
          $gte: moment().startOf('day').toDate(),
        },
      },
    },
    {
      $limit: 40,
    },
```

How could I achieve to add the limit inside an $and to get both together?

I tried with:

```
$match: {
        $and: [
          {
            offerDate: {
              $gte: moment().startOf('day').toDate(),
            },
            $limit: 40
          },
          {
            offerDate: {
              $lte: moment().startOf('day').toDate(),
            },
            $limit: 8
          },
        ]
      }
    },
```

But that didn't work at all and I cannot find the right way to do it.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[$limit](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/limit/) is a pipeline stage which cannot be used within any other stage so what you're trying is not the way to go. You simply need two separate `$matches` followed by `$limit` and the [$facet](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/facet/index.html) operator allows you to do that:

```
{
    $facet: {
        greater: [
            { $match: { offerDate: { $gte: moment().startOf('day').toDate() } } },
            { $limit: 40 }
        ],
        lower: [
            { $match: { offerDate: { $lte: moment().startOf('day').toDate() } } },
            { $limit: 8 }
        ]
    }
},
{
    $project: {
        all: { $concatArrays: [ "$greater", "$lower" ] }
    }
}
```

Comment: This looks definitely like a possibility BUT is it possible to have both results inside the same object?

Comment: @victorgonal sure, see my modified answer. You can go further with $unwind and $replaceRoot